# SwiftUI page control implementation

Tags: swiftui

I need to implement something like an animated page control. And I don't want to use integration with UIKit if possible. I have `pages` array containing 4 views I need to switch between. I create the animation itself by changing the value of `progress` variable using timer. And I have the following code right now

```
@State var pages: [PageView]
@State var currentIndex = 0
@State var nextIndex = 1
@State var progress: Double = 0

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isAnimating = true
            }) { shape.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if !self.isAnimating {
                    return
                }
                self.refreshAnimatingViews()
                }
            }.offset(y: 300)

        pages[currentIndex]
            .offset(x: -CGFloat(pow(2, self.progress)))
        pages[nextIndex]
            .offset(x: CGFloat(pow(2, (limit - progress))))
    }
}
```

It is animating great - current page is moved to the left until it disappears, and the next page is revealed from the right taking its place. At the end of animation I add `1` to both indices and reset `progress` to `0`. But once the animation (well not exactly an animation - I just change the value of progress using timer, and generate every state manually) is over, the page with index `1` is swapped back to page with index `0`. If I check with debugger, `currentIndex` and `nextIndex` values are correct - `1` and `2`, but the page displayed after animation is always the one I started with (with index `0`). Does anybody know why this is happening?

The whole code follows

```
struct ContentView : View {
    let limit: Double = 15
    let step: Double = 0.3
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    @State private var shape = AnyView(Circle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 60.0, height: 60.0, alignment: .center))

    @State var pages: [PageView]
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    @State var nextIndex = 1

    @State var progress: Double = 0
    @State var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isAnimating = true
            }) { shape.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if !self.isAnimating {
                    return
                }
                self.refreshAnimatingViews()
                }
            }.offset(y: 300)

            pages[currentIndex]
                .offset(x: -CGFloat(pow(2, self.progress)))
            pages[nextIndex]
                .offset(x: CGFloat(pow(2, (limit - progress))))
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }

    func refreshAnimatingViews() {
        progress += step
        if progress > 2*limit {
            isAnimating = false
            progress = 0
            currentIndex = nextIndex
            if nextIndex + 1 < pages.count {
                nextIndex += 1
            } else {
                nextIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    @State var title: String
    @State var imageName: String
    @State var content: String

    let imageWidth: Length = 150
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
            Text(title).font(Font.system(size: 40)).fontWeight(.bold).lineLimit(nil)
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: imageWidth, height: imageWidth)
                .cornerRadius(imageWidth/2)
                .clipped()
            Text(content).font(.body).lineLimit(nil)
        }.padding(60)
    }
}

struct MockData {
    static let title = "Eating grapes 101"
    static let contentStrings = [
        "Step 1. Break off a branch holding a few grapes and lay it on your plate.",
        "Step 2. Put a grape in your mouth whole.",
        "Step 3. Deposit the seeds into your thumb and first two fingers.",
        "Step 4. Place the seeds on your plate."
    ]
    static let imageNames = [
        "screen 1",
        "screen 2",
        "screen 3",
        "screen 4"
    ]
}
```

in SceneDelegate:

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let pages = (0...3).map { i in
                PageView(title: MockData.title, imageName: MockData.imageNames[i], content: MockData.contentStrings[i])
            }

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView(pages:
                pages))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Comment: How are progress, currentIndex and nextIndex defined?

Comment: Edited my question to include declarations, thank you

Comment: This still doesn't show any error. Can you share  the update and initialization code  too please.

Comment: Initialization is combined with declaration in my case and I added update code - and that's pretty much my whole program already

Comment: Please post a full example so we can replicate it. Thanks! I tried 10min to replicate it but didn't get it done.

Comment: Could you please give me an email to send the project to?

Comment: Stackoverflow usually wants to have everything necessary inside the post, so I rather not. Maybe it's possible to simplify it and post a complete example. Or may somebody else can solve it.

Comment: Here you go, I simplified as best I could, thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, Fabian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution works. I think the problem was switching out views while *SwiftUI* tries to diff and update them is not something *SwiftUI* is good at.

So just use the same two *PageView* views and swap out their content based on the current *index*.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct PagesView : View {
    let limit: Double = 15
    let step: Double = 0.3

    @State var pages: [Page] = (0...3).map { i in
        Page(title: MockData.title, imageName: MockData.imageNames[i], content: MockData.contentStrings[i])
    }

    @State var currentIndex = 0
    @State var nextIndex = 1

    @State var progress: Double = 0
    @State var isAnimating = false

    static let timerSpeed: Double = 0.01
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: timerSpeed, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    @State private var shape = AnyView(Circle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 60.0, height: 60.0, alignment: .center))

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isAnimating.toggle()
                self.timer = Timer.publish(every: Self.timerSpeed, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()
            }) { self.shape
            }.offset(y: 300)

            PageView(page: pages[currentIndex])
                .offset(x: -CGFloat(pow(2, self.progress)))
            PageView(page: pages[nextIndex])
                .offset(x: CGFloat(pow(2, (self.limit - self.progress))))
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                if !self.isAnimating {
                    return
                }
                self.refreshAnimatingViews()
        }
    }

    func refreshAnimatingViews() {
        progress += step
        if progress > 2*limit {
            isAnimating = false
            progress = 0
            currentIndex = nextIndex
            if nextIndex + 1 < pages.count {
                nextIndex += 1
            } else {
                nextIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page {
    var title: String
    var imageName: String
    var content: String
    let imageWidth: CGFloat = 150
}

struct PageView: View {
    var page: Page

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
            Text(page.title).font(Font.system(size: 40)).fontWeight(.bold).lineLimit(nil)
            Image(page.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: page.imageWidth, height: page.imageWidth)
                .cornerRadius(page.imageWidth/2)
                .clipped()
            Text(page.content).font(.body).lineLimit(nil)
        }.padding(60)
    }
}

struct MockData {
    static let title = "Eating grapes 101"
    static let contentStrings = [
        "Step 1. Break off a branch holding a few grapes and lay it on your plate.",
        "Step 2. Put a grape in your mouth whole.",
        "Step 3. Deposit the seeds into your thumb and first two fingers.",
        "Step 4. Place the seeds on your plate."
    ]
    static let imageNames = [
        "screen 1",
        "screen 2",
        "screen 3",
        "screen 4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and found out that the step that did it was not using only two page views. Just removing `@State` from PageView's variables declaration solves the problem